# Performant way to self-join and filter by revised rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select all rows in this table, with the constraint that revised id's are selected instead of the original ones. So, if a row has a revision, that revision is selected instead of that row, if there are multiple revision numbers the highest revision number is preferred.

I think an example table, output, and query will explain this better:

**Table:**

```
+----+-------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+
| id | value | original_id | revision_number | is_revision |
+----+-------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+
|  1 | abcd  | null        | null            |           0 |
|  2 | zxcv  | null        | null            |           0 |
|  3 | qwert | null        | null            |           0 |
|  4 | abd   | 1           | 1               |           1 |
|  5 | abcde | 1           | 2               |           1 |
|  6 | zxcvb | 2           | 1               |           1 |
|  7 | poiu  | null        | null            |           0 |
+----+-------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+
```

**Desired Output:**

```
+----+-------+-------------+-----------------+
| id | value | original_id | revision_number |
+----+-------+-------------+-----------------+
|  3 | qwert | null        | null            |
|  5 | abcde | 1           | 2               |
|  6 | zxcvb | 2           | 1               |
|  7 | poiu  | null        | null            |
+----+-------+-------------+-----------------+
```

**View Called `revisions_max`:**

```
SELECT 
    responses.original_id AS original_id,
    MAX(responses.revision_number) AS revision
FROM
    responses
 WHERE
    original_id IS NOT NULL   
GROUP BY responses.original_id
```

**My Current Query:**

```
SELECT
    responses.*
FROM
    responses
WHERE
    id NOT IN (
        SELECT
            original_id
        FROM
            revisions_max
    )
AND
    is_revision = 0

UNION

SELECT
    responses.*
FROM
    responses
INNER JOIN revisions_max ON revisions_max.original_id = responses.original_id
    AND revisions_max.revision_number = responses.revision_number
```

This query works, but takes `0.06` seconds to run. With a table of only 2000 rows. This table will quickly start expanding to tens or hundreds of thousands of rows. The query under the `union` is what takes most of the time.

What can I do to improve this queries performance?

Comment: Hey Douglas, your code won't run. "Column response_id does not exist". I cannot compare performances then.

Comment: @clapas woops, I'm converting from the table I'm working with to the simpler query example for stackoverflow. I'll fix that.

Comment: What indexes do you have on the table? How is your data distributed, i.e. what is the average number of revisions?

Comment: @GarethD There are no indexes at this time. Revisions seem to be ~1/50th of the tables data thus far. That may change as the number of users will be increasing by more than an order of magnitude soon (Internal company tool rollout)

Comment: @DouglasGaskell ERROR:  column "is_revision" does not exist

Comment: @clapas I added that column in my initial example table. I'm fully converting and running your example now, first run actually took less than 1ms where mine takes 60ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `coalesce()`?

```
SELECT COALESCE(y.id, x.id)                           AS id,
       COALESCE(y.value, x.value)                     AS value,
       COALESCE(y.original_id, x.original_id)         AS original_id,
       COALESCE(y.revision_number, x.revision_number) AS revision_number
FROM   responses x
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT r1.*
                  FROM   responses r1
                         INNER JOIN (SELECT responses.original_id          AS
                                            original_id,
                                            Max(responses.revision_number) AS
                                            revision
                                     FROM   responses
                                     WHERE  original_id IS NOT NULL
                                     GROUP  BY responses.original_id) rev
                                 ON r1.original_id = rev.original_id
                                    AND r1.revision_number = rev.revision) y
              ON x.id = y.original_id
WHERE  y.id IS NOT NULL
        OR x.original_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Clapas, I have edited my question. You may not have seen the changes before you answered. I've sorted out a solution, but want to improve it's performance now.

Comment: How does it compare? I cannot run your code, just post a comment.

Comment: Clapas, completely converted and ran yours, it performs MUCH better than mine. Though it is a bit hard on the eyes ;)

Now the big question is making the subqueries into views, and the related performance with that (I imagine it should be exactly the same)

Comment: Glad to help! I supposed it would run faster, because `NOT EXISTS` has usually bad performance.

Answer (score 1):

The approach I would take with any other DBMS is to use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT  r1.*
FROM    Responses AS r1
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    Responses AS r2
            WHERE   r2.original_id = COALESCE(r1.original_id, r1.id)
            AND     r2.revision_number > COALESCE(r1.revision_number, 0)
        );
```

To remove any rows where a higher revision number exists for the same id (or original_id if it is populated). However, in MySQL, [`LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` will perform better than `NOT EXISTS`](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)<sup>1</sup>. As such I would rewrite the above as:

```
SELECT  r1.*
FROM    Responses AS r1
        LEFT JOIN Responses AS r2
            ON r2.original_id = COALESCE(r1.original_id, r1.id)
            AND r2.revision_number > COALESCE(r1.revision_number, 0)
WHERE   r2.id IS NULL;
```

**[Example on DBFiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=d65e1325d5c7e5f1a9f91f53ffbab83b)**

I realise that you have said that you don't want to use `LEFT JOIN` and check for nulls, but I don't see that there is a better solution.

---

<sup>1. At least this was the case historically, I don't actively use MySQL so don't keep up to date with developments in the optimiser</sup>

Comment: Gareth, I just finished modifying my question right when you answered. I am reading through yours now. I got it to work and am focusing on performance.

Comment: Just tested, the `LEFT JOIN` & `COALESCE` version takes ~10x longer to run that the solution I ended up devising. Though it does appear to be much cleaner

Comment: I've removed a couple of unnecessary coalesces, and in the fiddle I have added an index (on original_id and revision_number), these both might help, but if the index helps my query then it is likely to speed up clapas's query even further.